# Reproducing formatting of MIX words/Text across multiple cells of a table

Tags: tables, knuth

I'd like to reproduce the formatting of MIX words in Knuth's *The Art of Computer Programming*. There is good example of what is giving me problems on the 3rd image on this page:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20924244/how-do-the-operations-lda-sta-sub-add-mul-and-div-work-in-knuths-machine-la

Namely, in the table at the center of that image,

|-|80|3|5|4|,

the "80" goes across two cells. How can I create the partial vertical lines "underneath" the 80?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not nice, but it works:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style = remember picture}

\newcommand{\myanchor}[1]{\tikz \node[coordinate] (#1) {};}

\usepackage{array} % used for setting extrarowheight

\begin{document}

\setlength\extrarowheight{1.5pt} % change to whatever font depth is
\begin{tabular}{*{6}{|c}|}
\hline
$ - $ & \myanchor{11} & \myanchor{12} & 3 & 5 & 4 \\
\hline
$ + $ & \myanchor{21} & \myanchor{22} & 3 & 5 & 4 \\
\hline
$ + $ & 0 & 0 & 3 & 5 & 4 \\
\hline
$ - $ & 0 & 0 & \myanchor{31} & \myanchor{32} & 3 \\
\hline
$ + $ & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\
\hline
$ - $ & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
$ + $ & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ? \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\setlength\extrarowheight{0pt} % reset

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\foreach \tmp in {1,2,3} {
  \node[
    shape     = rectangle,
    inner sep = 2pt,
    fill      = white,
    anchor    = base,
  ] at ($(\tmp1)!0.5!(\tmp2)$) {80};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]